# Transmission of Sound Waves

Tags: acoustics

If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around does it still make a sound ? I know the answer is supposed to be no, because the sound is created when it enters someone's ear. What if I left a tape recorder in the forest and a tree fell, then when I go back and listen to the tape recorder won't I hear the noise from the tree falling, even though I wasn't there ? So doesn't this mean that the tree falling still made a sound even though there was no one around to hear it ?

Comment: *"the sound is created when it enters someone's ear"* Why do you think that ???

Comment: Does a speaker vibrating at 50kHz make a sound?

Comment: @JánLalinský this is what an astronomer told me when I asked him this question, he told me that if there is no one in the forest then the tree didn't make a sound when it fell. I question this answer and that is why I am asking it here

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's purely philosophical, and bad philosophy at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sound isn't created until it enters the ear, then what travelled from the tree to the ear?

A sound wave is a travelling change in air pressure. The pressure disturbance is created when the tree falls, regardless of whether anyone is around (at least as far as physics is concerned). It then propagates, and may or may not encounter an ear.

If you ask the quantum equivalent of this question, you can go *way* down the rabbit hole and get into some heated discussions. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) may be a reasonable starting point, though if you don't have any experience with things quantum mechanical, learning some QM first is a must.

Comment: The sound was created but if no one is around then who is going to hear it ? So I think the reasoning is that if no one hears it then it didn't make a noise.

Comment: @PeterU could you please define what you mean by noise in that case? It seems like you're defining it as "something that gets heard", in which case your question is somewhat circular...

Comment: I didn't think this up on my own but heard this in a song "if a tree falls in a forest and no one is around did it make a sound" So this is what got me thinking about this and I came up with idea that if a tape recorder was left in the forest and the tree fell, later if I go back I'll hear the sound it made on the tape recorder, so that must mean that it did make a sound even when no one was around.I don't know why an astronomer told me that it doesn't make a sound if no one is around but I like your answer better.

Comment: @PeterU this still fails to define what you mean by "sound"/"noise"...